# ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE (HTTP Auth Error 407) on Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, proxy, puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const chalk = require('chalk');;
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const modules = require('./modules.js');
const randomInfo = require('./randomInfo.js');
const proxy = require('./proxies.js');

async function hello() {
    puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

    proxy.getProxy()

    this.accountMode = "1";

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        args: [`--proxy-server=${proxies.ip}:${proxies.port}`]
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.authenticate({
        username : proxies.user,
        password : proxies.pass
    });
    if (this.accountMode == "1" || this.accountMode == "2") {
        await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/register')
    } else if (this.accountMode == "3") {
        await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/')
    }
    console.log(chalk.cyan(`Using Proxy --- ${proxies.proxy}`)) 
}

hello()
```

After running the following code, the Puppeteer chrome browser will load successfully, but it will return a 407 error (Proxy Auth related). I have checked the values on all parts of the proxy in this case, and they are all correct. I have checked all my code numerous times and I cannot seem to find why I am having proxy auth issues.

Please let me know of a possible solution to this issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `proxies` is undefined, so `page.authenticate` won't have any credentials to push. Assuming you are using `getProxy` to get the proxy data, you would need to define it like:

```
const proxies = proxy.getProxy()
```

Note: This issue could also occur if the proxy provider isn't configured correctly (i.e. An non-whitelisted IP). You can find why this failure is occurring by enabling puppeteer's debug with:

```
DEBUG=puppeteer node hello.js
```

or adding it to the command you are using to run the code / adding it to the `package.json` command

Answer (score -1):

In my case I was using wrong credentials which caused this error. Used password instead of login and login instead of password. My suggestion is to double check credentials again.